# Why binding to a Service in another application fails? Explicit intent uses string parameters

Tags: android, android-intent

Trying to use Messenger to do ipc for a client to bind to a service as shown here.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle

My service is LaserApp in com.x.**laser**, the client is LaserClientActivity in com.x.**laserclient**.

The service is running as a **system** service and I have built client and service, signing both with the same certificates.

I get error:

> W/ContextImpl( 2468): Calling a method in the system process without a
>   qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.bindService:1762
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517
>   com.x.laserclient.LaserClientActivity.onStart:123
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart:1171

and

> android.app.Activity.performStart:5276   W/ActivityManager( 2053):
>   Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.x.laser/LaserApp } U=0: not
>   found

Note that the Explicit intent uses string parameters.

In the client, I bind thus:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to the service
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.x.laser", "LaserApp");
    // i.setClassName(this, LaserApp.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "bind to LaserApp ");
    bindService(i, mConnection,
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

The application that houses the service has manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.x.laser"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:name=".StartlaserApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/laser_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".LaserApp"
        android:exported="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainLauncher"
            android:label="@string/main_launcher" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the client manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.x.laserclient"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LaserClientActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**update**: I had to use fully qualified component name, make the client run as the same user id - system, and sign with the same certificates in order to get it to work. But to me, this undercuts the notion that any client can bind to a service. I don't understand but my immediate purpose was served

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
i.setClassName("com.x.laser", "LaserApp");
```

with this:

```
i.setClassName("com.x.laser", "com.x.laser.LaserApp");
```

The "class name" part of the `Component` must be fully qualified.

Comment: I did try it - based on your SO answer elsewhere and it did not work. I shall try again in case something changed that I hadn't taken into account.

Comment: This may be an issue in the way you've set this up as a system service. The error message about calling method without qualified user makes me nervous. Have you considered trying this using implicit `Intent` instead of explicit (just to see if you can get that to work)?

Comment: I had to make the client run as the same user id - system, and sign with the same certificates in order to get it to work. But to me, this undercuts the notion that any client can bind to a service. I don't understand but my immediate purpose was served.